# How to insert symbols in input text using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help in inserting html symbols like checkmark character using javascript.
Here is my code.

```
<script>
function me(){
var a = document.getElementById("me").value = 3;
if(a==3){
document.getElementById("u").value = "checkmark symbol here";
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="me" value=""/>
<input type="text" id="u" value="It will display here a checkmark symbol any symbo"/>
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="me()" />
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try copying `✓` or `✔`

Comment: Why do you try to insert symbols using javascript in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

The JS string `"\u2713"` should produce a checkmark (✓). In general, you can find the character you want on this site then copy the "C/C++/Java source code" section:
[Unicode Character 'CHECK MARK' (U+2713)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2713/index.htm).

Comment: The unicode will display sir, instead of a symbol. Can you give some example sir like my program format? :D

Comment: @VergelAndusAranas, simply replace `"checkmark symbol here"` by `"\u2713"`. Alternative, you can replace it by `"✓"` if the character encoding of the file containing the JavaScript code is UTF-8 and has been properly declared.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this

```
if (parseInt(document.getElementById("me").value)==3)
```

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. `'3' == 3`

Comment: Still, doesn't make a difference with or without `parseInt` because of coercion with `==`. In any case this doesn't seem to even address the question...

Comment: @elclanrs Of course =3 above should be removed in the first line.